# How to quit every instance of three.js when script is finished?

Tags: three.js

Please, I’d like to know how can I stop every instance of three.js when my script has finished? Is there a global `THREE.quit()` or something like that, because I don't think it’s a good solution to `.remove()` renderers, composers, cameras, scenes, meshes, backgrounds, and so on, et cetera.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When your instance runs in a div, you could remove the div or make it invisible.

Comment: THREE.js creates a canvas … so removing that canvas stops all renderers and scenes and whatever was started?

Comment: … because it seems some testing devices just keep on using extremely much CPU and GPU even after my script is run through. That’s why I asked in the first place how to just quit three.js …